# ssas compound dimension key

Tags: key, ssas, dimension, compound-key

I'm using SSAS Visual Studio 2010.  I have a dimension with a compound key pointing to a fact table.  To begin with, the compound key contained three keys, and now I need to add a fourth.  I did this in the DSV by clicking between the arrow between them and selecting the new fields from the dropdown menus.  So far so good.  I saved the DSV and reprocessed my cubes.  Here's where the problem starts:  I noticed only very minor changes in the relevant reports...  I expected either wholesale changes or nothing at all.  When I looked at the cube in Visual Studio, I noticed that "dimension usage" tab still showed only the three original keys - not the new fourth one.  However, in the cube, there are no dropdown menus to add the new key.  So now I'm a little stuck...  Do I have to delete it and recreate it?  I didn't want to do that unless absolutely necessary.  Also, if nothing changed in the cube, then what explains those tiny variances I noticed?  For example a cell showing $100,000 might be off by $15, but the vast majority of values were still spot on.

Answer (score 0):

When you change something in the DSV, it is not automatically added to your dimensions or measure groups. You have to manually go and add it there as well. In your case since you added a key, you might have to recreate that dimension specifying the new key's role in the dimension (This is if it does not work by only adding it in the dimension).
HTH

About the changing values, it usually has something to do with the keys, since that is used to aggregate the data (Other than that I can not say).